# Issue in appending a child nodes in jqtree after successfull ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tree, jqtree

I have an issue with appending child nodes to the tree. Scenario is,
I want to load the tree nodes onclick of node arrow using an ajax call. So, for getting tree structure initially am passing just the root level nodes to the tree, and the tree works fine , but when i click on arrow , it goes for an ajax call, it takes the next level of node hierarchy but it overrides the previous tree structure.

I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
      var $tree = $('#themes');
        $tree.tree({
            autoOpen: false,
                    dataUrl: "{% url 'get_root_hierarchy' grpid node.pk %}",
            });

        $tree.bind(
            'tree.open',
            function(event) {
                var node = event.node;                  
                $.ajax({
                  async : true,
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "{% url 'get_hierarchy' grpid %}?id=" + node.id,
                  datatype: "html",
                  success: function(data) {
                                      var data = $.parseJSON(data) ;
                                      $tree.tree({
                                          data:data
                                      });        
                  }

                });
            }
        );

    });

});
</script>

<div id="themes">  </div>
```

When i click on arrow for ajax call ,this manipulates and send the child nodes hierarchy, ajax success function receives the output properly, but it overrides the whole tree structure and then shows the new structure for that clicked node.
I wanted to append the child structure to the previous node structure, please suggest me how to acheive that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [append node](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#functions-appendnode) function?

```
success: function(data) {
     var data = $.parseJSON(data) ;
      $tree.tree(
        'appendNode', data, node
      );
   }
```

Comment: Yeah. I did it in same way. Thanks .